# Almost uniform convergence, equivalent definition

Tags: measure-theory

The definition of almost uniform convergence given by Bartle is this : $f_n$ is almost uniformly convergent if for each $\delta \gt 0 $ exist $E_{\delta}$ in $X$ with $\mu(E_{\delta}) \lt \delta$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $X$\ $E_{\delta}$

Now, I am wondering if this definition is equivalent : $f_n$ is almost uniformly convergent iff $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ except for a set of measure zero. That is, the definition of almost everywhere convergence (but changing pointwise convergence for uniform convergence)

Are these two definitions the same thing?

Edit : Now, thinking a little more about this, what I am proposing is Egoroff Theorem, right? We need to add the hypothesis $\mu(X) \lt \infty$, correct?

Answer (score 2):

If there exists a set $N$ of measure $0$ such that $\sup_{x\in X\setminus N}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\to 0$, then we do have almost uniform convergence, since we can choose $E_\delta=N$ for each $\delta$.

However, the converse is not true: take $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $X=[0,1]$ endowed with Lebesgue measure. The almost uniform convergence holds, because you can take $E_\delta=(1-\delta/2,1]$. Moreover, if $N$ has zero measure, then for each $k$, it contains at least an element in the interval $(1-1/k,1]$, say $x_k$ hence for each $n$, $$
\sup_{x\in [0,1]\setminus N}\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\geqslant \sup_{k\geqslant 1}x_k^n=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Le $f_n(x)=\frac 1 {nx}$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then, for any $\delta >0$ $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb R \setminus (0,\delta)$. Suppose $f_n \to 0$ uniformly outside  a set $E$ of mesare $0$. Then, there exists $N$ such that $f_n(x) <1$ for all $x\notin E$ and for all $n>N$. This implies that $f_n(x) \leq 1$ **for all $x$** and for all $n>N$  (because $E^{c}$ is dense) which is clearly false.

Answer (score 1):

No, these two definitions are not the same thing, and the difference lies in the nature of the exception sets in each definition.

In Bartle's definition of almost uniform convergence, for each $\delta >0 $, there exists a subset $E_\delta$ of $X$ with measure less than $\delta$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to f on the complement of $E_\delta$ (i.e., $X\setminus E_\delta$). This is a stronger condition than saying $f_n $ converges uniformly to $f$ except on a set of measure zero.

Why is it stronger? Because in Bartle's definition, for any given $\delta$, no matter how small, we can find a "negligible" set (with measure less than $\delta$ ) on which we allow non-uniform convergence, and everywhere else, we have uniform convergence. This means we can make the exception set as small as we want (less than any pre-specified $\delta$ ) and still have uniform convergence everywhere else.

On the other hand, saying that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ except on a set of measure zero is a weaker condition. Here, there's a single set of measure zero where we allow non-uniform convergence, and everywhere else, we have uniform convergence. This single set could be "large" in some sense (even though it has measure zero), and we cannot necessarily make it as small as any given $\delta$.

Comment: Making $\mu(X) \lt \infty $ would solve the “problem”? Or I am misunderstanding Egoroff theorem?